# Authenticate a GraphQL endpoint against Keycloak with custom response in Quarkus

Tags: java, graphql, keycloak, quarkus, quarkus-oidc

I want to secure a GraphQL API using authentication against Keycloak. This works fine by using the "quarkus-oidc" extension as described in the corresponding [guide](https://quarkus.io/guides/security-openid-connect). I simply added an "@Authenticated" annotation to the same method that has the "@Query" annotation. However, I also need to customize the 401 response in case of an authorization failure (because my client expects a JSON with some details). How can I do that?

I already tried adding an ExceptionMapper (as described [here](https://quarkus.io/guides/security-built-in-authentication#how-to-customize-authentication-exception-responses)), but it is not invoked. (It works for a standard REST endpoint, though.)

I also tried doing the authentication manually: I removed the "@Authenticated" annotation and instead injected a "SecurityIdentity" object. I then used the "hasRole" method, which throws an "AuthenticationFailedException" if authentication fails. I can catch this exception, but the default 401 response is already sent to the client in the background, and when I try sending any other response, I get an IllegalStateException ("Response head already sent")